# How to use cloud config in pxe boot?

Tags: boot, system-installation, pxe, cloud-init

I am using netbootxyz in order to boot my Ubuntu environments.
In matter of the facts, is that I am using pre-seed configuration.
The problem is that there are some minor bugs:

- gnome-terminal is not working.
- can not use post commands at all.

Could you please advise if you have used already the new installer, "cloud-config"?
How can I implement it since I really enjoy the netbootxyz container?